# Is there a way to send mail in php online?

Tags: php, email

I can send emails in PHP because I edited the php.ini file the the XAMPP directory. Then I uploaded my PHP file in a free domain, I can't send the email anymore because the php.ini file is obviously for xampp only. How can I send an email on an online domain?

Comment: Your English is fine.

Comment: You should check with the hosting service to find out how to send email from them.

Comment: You've left a lot for us to guess, but I presume you're using [mail()](https://php.net/mail) with the local SMTP server supplied by Xampp. Trust me, that path is not worth it, it's actually easier to drop `mail()` and use a third-party SMTP server with a third-party email library.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 3rd party services like twilio and use their API to send the mails , you can even send whatsapp messages through that

Comment: how can I use twilio? Sorry, I'm new to php and I'm just doing this because it's my project. I also need to send the email via Gmail if possible.

Comment: https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/api-getting-started here u will get the gist of what u will be using

Comment: and this is their official blog to send email using twilio and php https://www.twilio.com/blog/send-transactional-emails-php-twilio-sendgrid

Answer (score 0):

You can also configure a email sending service for apps like Sendgrid or equivalent in order to be able to send out emails.

Most hosting providers block SMTP port 21 to avoid issues with spammers.  The right way to do this is by using such a service I have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send mail with php, online, via Gmail...

1. Setup your project to use Composer.
   https://getcomposer.org/
2. Add phpmailer to your project through Composer
   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
   composer require phpmailer/phpmailer
3. Configure your Gmail to be able to use smtp from php
   Little tutorial regarding all described
   https://netcorecloud.com/tutorials/send-an-email-via-gmail-smtp-server-using-php/

Following all the steps, you'll be able to work/use your code in localhost with xampp or online, without changing anything